# How to access child component method from parent, provided if there are multiple child components?

Tags: angular5, parent-child, viewchild

I am looping a child component from a parent view. I want to create an instance for each child component and call that instance method of each child component from the parent component. Any help would be appreciated!!!

### Parent component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomComponent } from './custom.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let v of views">
       <customcomponent [name]="v" #cmp></customcomponent>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>
      {{components?._results | json}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  views = ['Sally','Manuel'];  
  @ViewChild('cmp') components:;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log( this.components.refreshMethod() );
  }

}
```

Here is the child component:

### child component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { CustomerService } from '../../../services/customer-service/customer-service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'Customcomponent',
      templateUrl: "./CustomComponent.html",
      styleUrls: ['../widget.css'],
      // template:` haiiiii this is fromwidgets.`,
    })
    //  ----------------------inheritence binding concept--------------------------->start
    export class CustomComponent  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      timerUnsubscribe: boolean;
      // ngAfterContentInit(): void {
      //   throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
      // }

      @Input() widget: any;


      @Output() event = new EventEmitter();

      public temp = [];
      needToRefresh: any;
      loader: boolean;

      constructor(public _custService: CustomerService) {
      }
      refreshMethod() {

      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log("Parent Destroy");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Loop over your components in the parent template: `<Customcomponent *ngFor="..." ></Customcomponent>`, this will create multiple "instances". I'm not sure what you mean by "calling an instance method of each child", as components in angular are usually "bound together" via the template by passing in `[data]` or listening to `(events)`.

Comment: Actually, I have service to call in child component. I want to call a method in that child component, from parent component. Generally, we create objects like ob1= new class();
ob2= new class();
ob1.methodName();
ob2.methodName();
Like that how do i create instance of thart child component and call a particular child component method

Comment: If you meed to call a service inside the child component, just let the dependency injection inject it in the child components constructor. Regarding the general interaction between components, I recommend this guide: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction